# How to link my existing MediaPlayer with lockscreen notification

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, mediacontroller, android-mediasession

Maybe the title isn't explicit enough, let me explain.

I am working on an already existing code, Java for Android app. The actual app have a mediaplayer playing audio stream, with only a play/pause button in the layout.
The played is initialized and used in an activity.
When the phone is locked, the stream continues to play but there is no notification displayed with the next previous etc buttons.

Using [this tutorial](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/using-android-media-style-notifications-with-media-session-controls/165) i managed to dispay the notification on lock screen and on notification area when i call this service from the activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MediaPlayerService.class);
intent.setAction(MediaPlayerService.ACTION_PAUSE);
startService(intent);
```

But it's obviously not working well as the already existing session is not linked to the new created controller on the notification.

So i'm wondering if it's better to:

- Use the new service i created and try to link it to existing session
- Dish the previous mediaplayer from the activity and handle all the media things in service
- Keep all the media handling in the activity

I'm not very familiar with Medias handling in Android.

Here is some preview of the actual code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_exercices);

    setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);
    mContext = this;


    // Init of MediaSession
    //mSession = new MediaSessionCompat(this, "MusicService");
    //mSession.setCallback(new MediaSessionCallback());
    //mSession.setFlags(MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS | MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);
    //setSessionToken(mSession.getSessionToken());


    mAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    mRemoteControlResponder = new ComponentName(getPackageName(),
            RemoteControlReceiver.class.getName());

    mStateBuilder = new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
                    .setActions(
                            PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY |
                                    PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE);

    initializeViews();
    initializeActions();
}


 public void initializeActions() {


        recyclerExercisesView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext));
        pAdapterExercise = new ExercisesPlayerAdapter(mContext, allExercisesList, isGuest, new ExercisesPlayerAdapter.RecyclerItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClickListener(Exercise exercice, int position) {
                //Toast.makeText(DetailsSceanceActivity.this, exercice.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                iv_play.setEnabled(true);
                seekBar_progress.setEnabled(true);

                if (!chronoLaunch && firstLaunch) {
                    startChrono();
                    startSensors();
                }
                firstLaunch = false;
                changeSelectedExercice(position);
                prepareExercise(exercice);
            }
        });
        recyclerExercisesView.setAdapter(pAdapterExercise);


        mMediaController = new MediaController(this);


        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MediaPlayerService.class);
        intent.setAction(MediaPlayerService.ACTION_PAUSE);
        startService(intent);

        // inint mediaplayer
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                // play song
                togglePlay(mp);
                //mMediaController.setMediaPlayer(this);
            }
        });

 }
```

I also saw few samples with MediaSessionCompat. Better use MediaSession or MediaSessionCompat?

Thanks

Comment: First, control your media session in a service. Second, set your notification privacy to public

Comment: MediaSession is mandatory? How to link it with my actual stream?

Comment: Not mandatory, but if you want your stream to keep on going when your activity is in the BG then use a service

Comment: Ok and do you have examples of use in a service with notifications ?

Comment: use this method from withing your service https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#startforeground and build a notification with actions to control the player

Comment: But the service already extend Service (from the tutorial i showed). Considering i already created a Mediaplayer in the activity, should i create another instance in the service or i can keep the activity one and "link" it to Mediasession in service? I hardly understand the communication between both